# Dividing Objects Below in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have a word that am busy cutting out of a box in Illustrator. I have all the letters cut out, except for 2 of them, which doesn't seem to want to "divide objects below".

For some reason the other letters are allowing to be "divide objects below" but these last two letters won't. It brings up the error message that "I have too many objects selected" but I only have one path selected at a time.

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot with the objects you're trying to cut out? With your layers panel and the error message if possible

Comment: Yes, a screenshot would help. I'm assuming the letters that "won't" work probably have multiple pieces to them... but it's hard to give advice without seeing what the problem is!